# How to change the $targer_dir to different folder Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to change the directory where the file is being upload. This is a new project for using CodeIgniter. 
Basically the code is as follows

```
if (isset($_FILES["abstract"]) && $_FILES["abstract"]["size"] != 0) {

                    $allowed_file_exts = array("doc", "docx", "rtf"); //"dot", "pdf"
                    $target_dir = $this->config->item("abstracts");
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                    $imageFileType = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["abstract"]["name"]), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

The current folder is "abstracts" if i change it to any other existing folder in the same directory the file is not saved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the other directories?

Comment: But that `$target_dir` is calling a config variable `'abstracts'`, not directly assign `'abstracts'` as upload directory

Comment: @HastaDhana bloody right..... Thank you for this i got confused and the folder is called as well abstracts..

Comment: Now i have $config["abstracts"] = FCPATH . "abstracts/";
This select the abstracts folder however i would like to select a subfolder depends ot the selected option.
$config["abstracts"] = FCPATH . "abstracts/" . $contribution_topic;
However this is not working properly any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      $config = array(
            'upload_path' => "public/your_path_under_public_directory",
            'allowed_types' => "jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
            'encrypt_name'=>TRUE
            );

            $new_name = time().$_FILES["caste_certificate"]['name'];
            $config['file_name'] = $new_name;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload("caste_certificate"))
            {
                $data = array($this->upload->data());
                $_POST['caste_certificate'] = $data[0]['file_name'];

            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message_error', $data['error'], 5);
                redirect(base_url()."branch/editprofile");
            }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why 

it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using the built in File Uploading Class. Have a look at here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append custom path after the base upload directory,
first leave the base upload directory like this :

```
$config["abstracts"] = FCPATH . "abstracts/";
```

and append with additional upload variable in your controller :

```
$target_dir = $this->config->item("abstracts") . $contribution_topic;
```

hope it helps..